# Flutter Image Compress Always giving error name.toLowerCase called on null

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-image

This is the code I am using.
I have checked it with different file format but still showing the same error, i have checked the "img.path" its showing the path to the image. I don't understand why I am getting an error.

```
String targetPath;
      var result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
        img.path,
        targetPath,
        quality: 88,
        format: CompressFormat.webp,
      );
```

Error I am getting:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: The method 'toLowerCase' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: toLowerCase()
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      Validator.checkFileNameAndFormat
package:flutter_image_compress/src/validator.dart:19
#2      FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile
package:flutter_image_compress/flutter_image_compress.dart:150
#3      _AddImageState.uploadFile
package:softclaw/…/addpost/addimage.dart:225
 #4      _AddImageState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:softclaw/…/addpost/addimage.dart:97
 <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: post the code from `flutter_image_compress.dart` line number `150`

Comment: nevermind, it is https://github.com/OpenFlutter/flutter_image_compress/blob/master/lib/flutter_image_compress.dart#L150 now check `_validator.checkFileNameAndFormat` method, line number `19`

Comment: line number 19 is name = name.toLowerCase();

Comment: so you have the answer why `toLowerCase` is called on `null` (the exact message: `Unhandled Exception: The method 'toLowerCase' was called on null.`)

Comment: so what should i do change the pub file? its a dependency from pub.dev

Comment: now `null` is passed to `checkFileNameAndFormat` method - thats why you got the exception

Comment: I tried to pass the name into FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile but there is no option to pass it

Comment: i can only pass the path to the image and the target path; where i am passing the path which is equal to /data/user/0/com.softclaw.in/cache/image_picker8531589453832627480.jpg

Comment: https://github.com/OpenFlutter/flutter_image_compress/blob/master/lib/src/validator.dart#L19 - do you see where `name` comes from?

Comment: name is coming from the main file  _validator.checkFileNameAndFormat(targetPath, format);

Comment: and there `null` is passed - thats why you have the exception

Comment: I passed name of file inplace of target path and its working now and not giving error too, but the result file is coming out null

Answer (score 1):

**targetPath** is the one that goes through the checkFileNameAndFormat > toLowerCase, therefore check to ensure this is not null.