# Flutter Image Compress giving result as null

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

Compressed is coming out as null

```
File compressed = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
        img.path,
        img.path.split('/').last,
        quality: 80,
      );

      ref = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child('postimages/${Path.basename(img.path)}');
      await ref.putFile(compressed);
```

This is what the error I am getting

> E/flutter (12851): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: 
> NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'absolute' was called on null.
> E/flutter (12851): Receiver: null
> E/flutter (12851): Tried calling: absolute
> E/flutter (12851): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
> E/flutter (12851): #1      Reference.putFile
> package:firebase_storage/src/reference.dart:126
> E/flutter (12851): #2      _AddImageState.uploadFile
> package:softclaw/…/addpost/addimage.dart:228
> E/flutter (12851): 
> E/flutter (12851):

Comment: instead of `img.path.split('/').last` you have to pass a full path - a full path where compressed file will be written to

Comment: that is the target path, if i pass full path it'll say image path can't be same as image path, and if i pass another path then it'll ask name of image; so instead of path i passed the name of file.

Comment: no, if path is `/this/is/some/path` then passing `path.split('/').last` will give `path` as it is last segment - why dont you simply `print` what you pass to `compressAndGetFile`?

Comment: run `void main() {
print('/foo/bar/image.png'.split('/').last);
}` on https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ for example and you will see what you are passing now

Comment: well this is the img.path /data/user/0/com.softclaw.in/cache/image_picker8531589453832627480.jpg  and  img.path.split('/').last is image_picker8531589453832627480.jpg

Comment: I know what i am passing, but that dependency wasn't working if i won't pass the name that why i am passing this

Comment: `image_picker8531589453832627480.jpg` is not a full path to the filesystem - it should be something like `/data/user/0/com.softclaw.in/cache/image_picker8531589453832627480.webp` or something

Comment: this dependency is asking for a path to image and the target path, if i don't pass name of file in target path it will show error "name is null" ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68821346/flutter-image-compress-always-giving-error-name-tolowercase-called-on-null?noredirect=1#comment121628802_68821346 look we already discussed about it

Comment: what is unclear with "is not a full path to the filesystem"? i gave an example how it should look like, again it should be `/data/user/0/com.softclaw.in/cache/image_picker8531589453832627480.webp` and not any simple name like `image_picker8531589453832627480.jpg`

Comment: I have tried this to by passing same path in both places like this guy https://youtu.be/hV9gY01m61Y?t=902 but now we can't pass same path in both fields

Comment: so did you try to pass `/data/user/0/com.softclaw.in/cache/image_picker8531589453832627480.webp` ?

Comment: Yes and it gave error saying they both can't be same

Comment: `FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile("/data/user/0/com.softclaw.in/cache/image_picker8531589453832627480.jpg", "/data/user/0/com.softclaw.in/cache/image_picker8531589453832627480.webp", quality: 80, format: CompressFormat.webp);` - what is the same? input is `jpg` output is `webp`

Comment: It worked with this format: CompressFormat.webp

Comment: but it worked manually how will i pass the changed format path automatically?

Comment: i have no idea what you mean by manually

Comment: File compressed = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
          "/data/user/0/com.softclaw.in/cache/image_picker8531589453832627480.jpg",
          "/data/user/0/com.softclaw.in/cache/image_picker8531589453832627480.webp",
          quality: 80,
          format: CompressFormat.webp);   here in place of original file i can pass img.path but what will i pass in place of .webp file?

Comment: `final path = '/data/user/0/com.softclaw.in/cache/image_picker8531589453832627480.jpg'); final imageUri = Uri.parse(path);
final outputUri = imageUri.resolve('output.webp');
print(imageUri.toFilePath());
print(outputUri.toFilePath());`

Comment: @pskink   Any chance you can write the final result up in an answer, so we can upvote and OP can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work perfectly fine

```
final imageUri = Uri.parse(img.path);
      final String outputUri = imageUri.resolve('./output.webp').toString();
      print(imageUri.toFilePath());

      File compressed = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
          img.path, outputUri,
          quality: 80, format: CompressFormat.webp);
      print(img.path);
      print(outputUri);

      ref = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child('postimages/${Path.basename(img.path)}');
      await ref.putFile(compressed);
      _imageName.add(await ref.getDownloadURL());
    }
```